# Understanding average Iq of buck boost converter (skipping and switching modes)

Tags: low-power, buck-boost

I'm trying to pick a buck boost converter for a low power, small battery, long life device.

The datasheets specify different supply currents for different modes and I just can't wrap my head around what they mean...

For instance this one, MAX77827
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX77827.pdf

It has a low shutdown Iq of 0.1 uA. That's quite clear, when EN is low the chip does nothing and consumes 0.1 uA.
But what about a highly variable load? There are figures for Iq_SKIP & Iq_PWM. The pulse skipping is in the low uA (desirable) and the PWM value in the low mA (ludicrously high).

The datasheet states that

> Transition from skip mode
> to PWM occurs when load current increases past a certain threshold

But there is no other mention of said threshold. How am I to know if the chip will draw an extra few uA or a few extra mA for my given load?

The "Typical operation characteristics" section graphs among other things, efficiency vs load all the way up to the maximum output current. There is also a note that specifies the testing conditions. It says pulse skipping mode unless otherwise noted. And there are no notes on the graphs with eta vs load. To me, that sounds like it uses pulse-skipping mode all the way up to the maximum load. Which just does not make sense... There is also a graph that shows efficiency in forced PWM mode. Is it reasonable to think that the magic threshold max load for pulse skipping mode is where the forced PWM graph meets the unspecified graphs perhaps?
[image: Graph]
And if that's the only hidden place to find the threshold level, could someone please give me some pity? Shouldn't this level be of primary concern for every designer?!

Comment: Looks to be around 200 mA load current to me.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes perhaps my arrow was a bit off, but you mean that the threshold IS where the lines cross each other? So anything below that is likely in skip mode?

Comment: I would say so but, given the data sheet isn't explicit about this threshold, it's hard to be precise.